# Vue async request with axios

Tags: javascript, vue.js, async-await

Description:

I'm encountering an issue with a Vue.js component where playerEl.value becomes null after an asynchronous Axios request, causing the component to fail to render.

Problem:

I have a Vue.js component where I'm fetching some data asynchronously using Axios in the onMounted hook. After fetching the data, I'm trying to append a player element to a div with the ID player, which is referenced by a ref named playerEl. However, it seems that playerEl.value becomes null after the Axios request, leading to a failure in rendering the component.

```
<script setup>
import { onMounted, ref } from "vue";
import axios from "axios";
var gameData;
const slug = window.location.pathname.split('/').pop();

const playerEl = ref(null);

onMounted(async () => {
  try {
    const response = await axios.get(`https://api.flasoyun.com/game/${slug}`);
    gameData = response.data;
    console.debug(gameData)
    const ruffle = window.RufflePlayer.newest();
    const player = ruffle.createPlayer();
    playerEl.value.appendChild(player);
    //const slug = window.location.pathname.split('/').pop();
    player.load(`/games/${slug}.swf`);

  } catch (error) {
    console.error('Error fetching game data:', error);
  }
});
</script>

<template>
  <div>
    <div class="container">
      <div class="row g-4">
        <div class="col-lg-8 mx-auto">
          <h2>{{ gameData.title }}</h2>
          <div class="ratio ratio-16x9">
            <div id="player" ref="playerEl"></div>
          </div>

          <div>
            {{ gameData.content }}
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</template>
```

Comment: "playerEl.value becomes null" - how do you know? If there's an error, please, list it entirely. It could be so if a component has been unmounted at this point. The mistake here is that gameData is undefined and not reactive, it's gameData.title that can make it fail to render

Comment: `gameData` is initially undefined, but the component must immediately on creation render values that don't exist, `gameData.title` and `gameData.content`.  These kind of uncaught errors can stop code execution, so the problem with `playerEl` probably isn't the _actual_ problem and you need to fix the underlying issues first.  Add `v-if="gameData"` on the parent div and see what issues persist. Also in the future please be sure to add the actual error messages to your question.

Comment: surely `gameData` needs to be reactive

Comment: yep makin gameData reactive solved the issue, thanks